# RawMaterialButton doesn't show the drop shadow

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm trying to do a custom button using RawMaterialButton in Flutter, I was expecting to see a dropshadow when I set the elevation - however, it looks flat on my screen:

```
Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: RawMaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),

                    onPressed: (){},
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text("SomeText")),

                    fillColor: Colors.blue,

                    elevation: 2.0,

                    ),
                )
```

How do I show a dropshadow without having to custom apply a decoration ?

Comment: why not just use a `RaisedButton` ?

Comment: the docs say: *"This class does not use the current Theme or ButtonTheme to compute default values for unspecified parameters. It's intended to be used for custom Material buttons that optionally incorporate defaults from the themes or from app-specific sources."* - why dont you customize "normal" button instead?

Comment: Although he could likely use RaisedButton, why the elevation is not showing up on RawMaterialButton is still a very good question that I too cannot find the answer for.